# XML to HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, yii

I'm trying to convert this XML feed below to a HTML table using php

```
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>
Latest consumer reviews on abc.com from 28/09/2015
</title>
<link>https://www.example.com</link>
<description>
<![CDATA[ bla bla bla bla. ]]>
</description>
<item>
<title>2015 AUDI A1 SPORTBACK TFSI</title>
<link>
http://localhost/frontend/www/audi/a1/2015/
</link>
<pubDate>1443607871</pubDate>
<enclosure length="" type="image/jpeg"/>
<guid isPermaLink="true">
http://localhost/frontend/www/audi/a1/2015/
</guid>
<date>30/09/2015</date>
<time>10:11</time>
<id>1</id>
<image>
https://example.com/audi.jpg
</image>
</item>
<item>
<title>2015 BMW 3series</title>
<link>
http://localhost/frontend/www/bmw/3/2015/
</link>
<pubDate>1444117968</pubDate>
<enclosure length="" type="image/jpeg"/>
<guid isPermaLink="true">
http://localhost/frontend/www/bmw/3/2015/
</guid>
<date>06/10/2015</date>
<time>07:52</time>
<id>2</id>
<image>
https://example.com/bmw.jpg
</image>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

in my php code i have this

```
$baseurl = 'http://localhost/frontend/www/';
$url = $baseurl.'comment/rss/comments/?t='.time().'&l=4';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, 0, TRUE);

foreach($xml->channel AS $x) {
        print_r($x);
}
```

but what i output's when i `print_r` is not the full array of `<item>`. All i get is this

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => Latest consumer reviews on example.com from 28/10/2015 [link] => https://www.example.com [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
```

Didn't include the HTML part coz i cant even get the loop to work properly. any idea on what i'm missing or doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using XMLtoArray library (http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-xml-to-array-in-php-xml2array/) instead.

It would convert your xml in a multidimensional array and from there looping through the array would be an easy job

You updated code should look like

```
$baseurl = 'http://localhost/frontend/www/';
$url = $baseurl.'comment/rss/comments/?t='.time().'&l=4';
$xml = file_get_content($url,true);
$array = XML2Array::createArray($xml);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: now it gives me `Array ( [channel] => Array ( [title] => Latest consumer reviews on example.com from 28/10/2015 [link] => https://www.example.com [description] => Array ( [@cdata] => bla bla bla. ) ) [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 2.0 ) )`

Comment: my foreach loop is this tho `foreach($array AS $x) {
              print_r($x);
      }`

Comment: Yes that correct try printing $array and you will understand why you are getting this array

Comment: To access the description try `echo $x["channel"]["description"]["@cdata"]`

Comment: but where is `<item>` ? it doesn't show in the array. why?

Comment: There is some confusion, I think may be because of the foreach loop. Simply print the array and you will get an idea of array structure

Comment: well `foreach($array AS $x) { print_r($x); }` still doesnt show `<item>` this is the array it gives. `Array ( [channel] => Array ( [title] => Latest consumer reviews on example.com from 29/10/2015 [link] => https://www.example.com [description] => Array ( [@cdata] => bla bla bla. ) ) [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 2.0 ) ) `

Answer (score 0):

You can also use XSLT to transform your XML into HTML.

```
$baseurl = 'http://localhost/frontend/www/';
$url = $baseurl.'comment/rss/comments/?t='.time().'&l=4';

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML(file_get_contents($url));

$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load('feed-to-html-table.xsl');

$xsltp = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsltp->importStyleSheet($xsl);
echo $xsltp->transformToXML($xml);
```

And the `feed-to-html-table.xsl` XSL stylesheet could be something like this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/rss/channel">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="{link}"><xsl:value-of select="title" /></a></td>
      <td><img src="{image}" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="date" /> <xsl:value-of select="time" /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```